# What's the difference between looping through an array and using array.every()

Tags: actionscript-3

What's the difference between looping through an array or using array.every() to assign a callback to each array element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array.every() function uses a test callback function on each array element, but stops once that test function returns false. If you loop through the array, it will go through every element regardless. In other words, the array.every() function is more properly used to test if every element of an array fits a certain criteria. See [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#every%28%29) of array.every() for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to check if every element of your array is of type `IFoo`, and depending on that perform a certain operation.

There are at least 3 ways to do this.

**1. Iteration**

```
var allFoo:Boolean = true;
for (var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (!(array[i] is IFoo)) {
    allFoo = false;
    break;
  }
}

if (allFoo) {
  // perform operation
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

**2. Enumeration**

```
var allFoo:Boolean = true;
for each (var e:* in array) {
  if (!(e is IFoo)) {
    allFoo = false;
    break;
  }
}

if (allFoo) {
  // perform operation
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

**3. Array.every()**

```
function isElementFoo(item:*, index:int, array:Array):Boolean
{
  return (item is IFoo);
}

if (array.every(isElementFoo)) {
  // perform operation
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

I expect the second one to be the fastest, whereas the third one is the most elegant due to the absence of any temporary variables. Ultimately which one you choose depends on the nature of your program as much as your own personal style and philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically a convenience function that abstracts common uses of for or while loops on arrays. To make it a little quicker to code and depending on you preferences a little clearer to read.

You would get a little bigger overhead using array.every since it does a function call for every element butt this is a none issue in 99.99...% of the time especially on the flash platform.